# How do I make my RSS Reader take in different URL and fetch their RSS Feed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, rss

I have a working RSSreader, but it only works with 1 url that you hardcode inside the main activity. I want to make it so that I have a EditField and it can take in any URL I decide to put and fetch the RSS with a button.

My current code below -

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");


        boolean insideItem = false;

        // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the     headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of    article
                }
            }else if(eventType== XmlPullParser.END_TAG &&   xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listrssreader);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int    position, long id) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse((String)links.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public void fetch(View v){

}

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try {
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}


}
```

Right now I managed to get it to work. As soon as I launch the application it goes straight to the listview of different RSS feeds. I want to launch the application and have only the Textfield and the fetch button. After I put in the URL and press the fetch button it goes to the listview of rss feeds.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: My list view is the first thing that pops up with the rss feed. I want it to have a textfield where I can type a url and I can fetch the rssfeed . And then the list view comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it says

```
  URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");
```

Replace the link with a string.

```
String link = /*insert URL from user input (maybe from a EditText) */
```

So now it looks like `URL url = new URL(link);`

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Declare an activity with an EditText that will receive your URL,together with a button call Start button.
- Step 2: Click on the button, your obtain the url in the edittext and pack it into an Intent, then call startAcitity(Intent)
- Step 3: In the RSS Listview Activity, extract the URL given and load your RSS list to your listview.

Simple, right?